# vulnerability from security team in forget password controller in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, websecurity

I have a controller form application and the security team they said there is a vulnerability you can put any user_id fom postman inside the controller like this

ForgotPassword/**user_id**

how I can remove this vulnerability check the code below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult ForgotPassword(string emailId)
    {

        var helper = new Helper.Helper();
        List<SqlParameter> args = new List<SqlParameter>();
        args.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pin_email_id", emailId));
        var req_resp = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        try
        {
            using (DataSet dataset = helper.ExecuteSqlQuery("Web_Forgot_Password", args))
            {
                if (dataset != null && dataset.Tables.Count > 0 && dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Status"].ToString() == "Success")
                    {
                        req_resp["status"] = true;
                        req_resp["message"] = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                        req_resp["code"] = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Code"].ToString();
                        string password = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_password"].ToString();
                        SendForgotMail(emailId, dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["user_name"].ToString(), helper.Decrypt(password), dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["employee"].ToString());

                        return Json(req_resp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        req_resp["status"] = false;
                        req_resp["message"] = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
                        req_resp["code"] = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Code"].ToString();
                        return Json(req_resp);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    req_resp["status"] = false;
                    req_resp["message"] = "Request Failed";
                    req_resp["code"] = "1005";
                    return Json(req_resp);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            var response = new
            {
                status = false,
                message = "Request failed",
                code = "1005"
            };
            return Json(response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the vulnerability exactly?

Comment: vulnerability cause the possibility to be attacked from hackers

Comment: if you have implemented any API security mechanism like jwt token based auth then your API will not be vulnerable.

Comment: There is a clear case of a directory harvesting attack here. And the fact that this code can be used to spam emails with forgot password emails.

Answer (score 0):

Well normally you store only password hashes in your database, which are not decryptable. Watching `helper.Decrypt(password)` in your code and sending the original password as a plain text in email is something painful. Normally I would just send a password reset link which can be used only once.

I checked the SqlParemater docs, it is added as a String value the way you use it, so it is not SQL injectable. Without the exact SQL I cannot tell much. I think they meant that it is SQL injectable, but then they should send evidence at least.